# Log the response time of DW queries in RStudio

Tags: sql, r, logging, shinyapps

I want to capture the start time, end time, and duration of the main usage data query to a file through RStudio and also gives the file maximum size and how many days of data can we store.

I know the method to define Sys.time() before and end of the query to get the execution time but I am looking for a standard format that gives me all the above things including file size without manually defining anything.  (More of something like structured logging)

This is how I tried it before, but now I want it in standard format.

```
library(log4r) 
log_file <- "File.log" 
file_logger <- logger("DEBUG", appenders = file_appender(log_file)) 
start_time <- Sys.time() 
sql <- paste0("select C1, C2 from DB WHERE ID = ", input$ID)
query_result = GetQueryResult(sql_query) 
end_time <- Sys.time() 
duration <- difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "secs") 
log4r::debug(file_logger,paste0("| START_TIME: ", start_time, " | END_TIME: ", end_time, " | QUERY_RESPONSE_TIME: ", round(duration, 2), " seconds"))
```

Here GetQueryResult function has the odbcConnect and sqlQuery functions which returns the result of sql_query.

Comment: Where do you intend to store this? Getting the two times is as simple as storing `Sys.time()` before and after your query, and then subtracting the two for the duration, from there "what" you do with it is entirely contextual. Do you want it in the logs? Use `cat`, `message`, `logger::log_info`, or any other number of ways to dump the three stats into the log. Do you want it in the database? It seems straight-forward enough if you have a table with (among many others) three columns "QueryStart", "QueryEnd", and "QueryDuration".

Comment: Side note: if you're going to stick with "new connection each function call", then I strongly recommend better resilience to a failed query (for _any_ reason, even intermittent). Options, not mutually-exclusive: (1) immed after `odbcDriverConnect(.)`, place `on.exit(odbcClose(handle1))` (and remove it later); (2) wrap `sqlQuery(.)` in `result <- tryCatch(sqlQuery(.), error=function(e)e)` and then `if (inherits(result, "error"))` do something _specific_ (such as warn about it and/or return some reasonable "empty data", up to you contextually).

Comment: The "risk" of not doing this is that any hiccup or failure in the query will likely result in orphaned/zombie connections on the server. Granted, R will eventually garbage-collect the connections from its end, and this "should" close them on the remote end, but not all drivers handle things like this as gracefully. Even if you don't see issues from R, there could still be mild consequences on the server itself on which you have zero visibility. Just my two cents.